How to achieve smooth sinusoidal function with fast reset?
I am looking for an expression to create a smooth sinusoidal-based function that rises sinusoidally from $-1$ to $+1$ and resets rather fast back to $-1$. If we consider a piecewise function, it is pretty straightforward to do. (See the plot below) 
However, it becomes complicated if we want to achieve a smooth function. Do you have any ideas how to do this? Would it be possible via frequency modulation of a sinusoidal signal?
I am not particularly interested in how the reset looks like as long as it is smooth. While playing with Desmos' graphing calculator, I was able to achieve fast resets with some oscillations and that is perfectly fine for my application, however, I wasn't able to achieve the repeating pattern that you see in the plot above.
Edit: As noted in some answers, I would like to clarify that by continuous I mean infinitely differentiable.

You could Fourier analyze the shape you have drawn.  It will express the function as a sum of sine waves.  The more sine waves you add in, the faster the transition will be.  You need high frequencies to get sharp corners.  Because of the discontinuity, you will overshoot at the corners.  The overshoot will get taller and narrower as you take more terms.  If you make the drop steep but not quite vertical it will get much better.  Any finite sum of terms will be infinitely differentiable.  The fundamental will have a full period of $2.5$ nsec

Lets first define
$$r(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor $$
which goes linearly from $x=0$ to $x=1$ with speed 1 (so like $y=x$) and then $r$estarts. For more control you could use
$$ r_{c}(x) =  c r\left(\frac xc\right) =  x -  c \left\lfloor\frac xc\right\rfloor$$
which goes linearly from $x=0$ to $x=c$ with speed $1$.
Say you have a signal $s$ (perhaps $s(x)=\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+1$) which may or may not be periodic. To get the discontinuous restart, replace $y=s(x)$ with $y=s(r_c(x))$.  Example on Desmos:

In fact, this procedure converts any function $s$ into a periodic one with period $c$.
There are at least two things you could do to make this continuous. One is to make the signal go back on itself starting from some transition time $t$ until $c$, as follows:
$$
\phi_0(x) = \begin{cases}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\right) & |x|<1,\\
0 &|x|\ge 1,
\end{cases} \\
\phi(x) = \frac{\int_{0}^{1-x}\phi_{0}\left(2z-1\right)dz}{\int_{0}^{1}\phi_{0}\left(2z-1\right)dz}\\
b_{c,t}(x) = x \phi\left(\frac{x-t}{c-t}\right), \qquad y=s(b_{c,t}(r_c(x)))
$$ The function $\phi$ is a variant of this 'well-known' bump function which is indeed smooth (in the precise sense of $C^\infty$). On the interval $[0,t]$, the function perfectly matches $s$.
Here I am varying $t$ (yellow line) from $0$ to $c=3$:

(a small lie: I have used the wrong function in the graphs so they are only twice differentiable. But they render much quicker since Desmos does not need to numerically evaluate integrals)
The second way would rely on the signal returning to its original value at some point in the future, say $s(p) = s(0)$ for some $p$. (for $s(x)=\sin(x-\pi/2) + 1$, $p=2\pi$.) The idea is to speed up the signal until we reach $p$ (smoothly). One can do this as follows:
$$
\psi(x) = 1 - \phi(x), \\ 
B_{c,t,p}(x)=x+\left(p-c\right)\psi\left(\frac{x-t}{c-t}\right), \qquad y=s(B_{c,t,p}(r_c(x))
$$

These functions are available in this Desmos graph.
It doesn't look as pleasant in this example because the maximum of the signal is beyond $c$, so the signal rushes the maximum point before dropping back down. By modifying the parameters to
\begin{align}
c &= \pi + 0.317\\ t &= 3.3
\end{align}
we can achieve the following


I note that although you said 'smooth', this word is a little imprecise and in the above I ensured the function is infinitely differentiable. There are simpler functions that you can use in place of $\phi$ (and hence $\psi$) if continuity is all that is required (as might be implied by the tags). I'll leave finding this simpler $\phi$ up to the reader.
Finally I just want to point out that since this method smoothly varies the frequency it equally applies to arbitrarily complex signals, and the result will be as smooth as and as discontinuous as the original signal. Example:


I didn't notice in the question that we're after a smooth version; im out of time right now but its not hard to improve this once we have decoupled the problem into the signal $s$ and some restarting function $r$. Will update later

Thank you for your answer! Yes, the main problem here is how to achieve a smooth function.

(Excusions for using Mathematica code)
A smooth function cannot be discontinous. Take the mod of the argument on the basis $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$
Plot[Sin  [Mod[(\[Pi] x)/5, \[Pi], -\[Pi]/2]  ], {x, -2.5, 7.5}, 
    Ticks -> Automatic, Exclusions -> None]

or  manipulate the sign
Plot[ (-1)^ Round[ x/5] Sin[(\[Pi] x)/5] , {x, -2.5, 7.5}, 
 Ticks -> Automatic, Exclusions -> None]

Both yield the same plot.

A nice family of smooth functions approaching such rectangular projection waves are provided by the quotients of Jacobi's elliptic theta functions of modulus m, that interpolate between sinuiodal $m=0$ and rectangular periodic for $m=1$ of period
  FunctionPeriod[EllipticTheta[1, x, m]/EllipticTheta[4, x, m], x] == 2\[Pi]

 Manipulate[ Plot[ 
     - (EllipticTheta[1, 2 ( x - 2.5)/\[Pi], m]/
         EllipticTheta[4, 2 (x - 2.5)/\[Pi], m]) * 
       Sin[(\[Pi] x)/5] , 
     {x, 0,  15}, Ticks -> Automatic, Exclusions -> None, ImageSize -> 150], 
  {{m, .8}, 0.1, 0.99}]



Thank you! I tried the code in Mathematica and also translated it to Python. It is indeed what I was looking for. However, I am still curious if similar result can be achieved by frequency modulation of $f(t)=-cos(2\pi ft)$.


Notice that transitioning from red curve ($-\cos(x)$) to the black one ($\cos(x)$) near $x=0$ yields the pattern you need. So, first we take a smooth transition function defined in a small neighbourhood (say, $(-a,a)$) around $0$.
$$f(x)=\frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{x+a})}{\exp(-\frac{1}{x+a})+\exp(-\frac{1}{a-x})}$$
Now let’s define the actual transition:
$$g(x)=\begin{align}\begin{cases}
-\cos x &x<-a\\
f(x)\cdot\cos x+(1-f(x))\cdot(-\cos x)&|x|\leq a\\
\cos x &x>a
\end{cases}\end{align} $$
Repeating this pattern with a period of $\pi$ :
$$g(\tan^{-1}(\tan x))$$

Desmos graph: link
This function is infinitely differentiable.
